# Separate and display multiple json value in different span tag in reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a `json` object called `blogData` with json data. Inside the json obj the `tags` key may have multiple tag values. I would like to display the tags values separately in `span` tag while iterating using map function.

Now multiple tags are displaying in a single span tag ( please see below) How can I fix this ?

[image]

```
const blogData = [
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "title":"Cypress tests",
      "images":"/images/image1.jpg",
      "description": "Add the E2E cypress UI tests",
      "tags": "cypress"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "title":"Jmeter tests",
        "images":"/images/image2.jpg",
        "description": "Performance test using Jmeter tool",
        "tags": ["jmeter", "performance"]
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "title":"Basic Unix commands",
        "images":"/images/image3.jpg",
        "description": "Learn basic unix commands in git bash",
        "tags": "unix"
    },
    {
        "id" : 4,
        "title":"Postman",
        "images":"/images/image4.jpg",
        "description": "Api testing using postman",
        "tags": ["postman", "api"]
    },
]
```

`Home.js`

```
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);        

               <div className="container">
                    {
                    searchResults.map(({ id, title, images, description, tags }) => (
                        <div key={id} className="column-center">
                            {/* <img className="blogImage" key={images} src={images} alt="image"></img> */}
                            <div className="blogtitle">
                                <span key={title}>{title}</span>
                            </div>
                            <section>
                            <p className="blogdescription" key={description}>{description}</p>
                            </section>
                            <section className="col1">
                                <span key={tags}>{tags}</span>
                            </section>
                            <section className="col2">
                                <a>Read more {'>'}{'>'}</a>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                      ))
                    }
               </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this what you are after.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-lewin-uo0yb?file=/src/App.js:1233-1422)

```
<section className="col1">
  {Array.isArray(tags) ? (
    tags.map((tag) => (
      <span style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}>{tag}</span>
    ))
  ) : (
    <span>{tags}</span>
  )}
</section>
```

You could make this code much simpler be having the `tags` field always be an array even if there is a single element.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I didn't think we should iterate again in this case. Much appreciated for your help.  Not sure why someone  downvoted in my question though.. I have upvoted  and accepted your answer.

Comment: I am guessing the reason you were downvoted (it wasn't me) is because you didn't provide a working example (use codesandbox) and because your question code was a bit of a mess for the person answering to sort out.